# Does a technical solution exist to open a .mpr file in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have to read informations from a .mpr file (in order to complete a dataset). Does anyone know how it works ?
I tried with pandas, open(), but on the net i got anything ..

Thanks a lot !

Comment: What is a `.mpr` file? How is it generated?

Comment: it is generated from ECLAB and BTLAB softwares for making chemical studies. It looks like a .csv (or a .txt) file on the software. The extension is specific of these softwares normally.

Comment: If it is a `csv` or a `txt` file - i.e. a delimited file - you can use `pandas.read_csv('/path/to/data.mpr')`

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a csv of txt file. The extension .mpr is owner by the software ... That's why I'm trying to open it in a different way.

Answer (score 3):

There's a package on GitHub called galvani that you can use. Install from source (it seems that their pip install galvani is not updated)

Then simply do:

```
from galvani import BioLogic as BL
import pandas as pd

mpr = BL.MPRfile('path_to_your.mpr')
df = pd.DataFrame(mpr.data)
df.head()
```

You will see your data